# using Window.alert() in a playn project

Tags: gwt, client-side, playn

Just for testing I tried to use the Window.alert() function from the com.google.gwt.user.client.Window package in my playn project. But when I try to run the programm I got an Error Message like this:

"Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: ERROR: GWT.create() is only usable in client code!  It cannot be called, for example, from server code.  If you are running a unit test, check that your test case extends GWTTestCase and that GWT.create() is not called from within an initializer or constructor.
"

I really do not understand it. In my playn project is only client side code in use. So what's the problem?

Comment: can you provide the code snippet? Window.alert never made any problems for me, so I'm courious...

Comment: Update: It works fine as a Web Application, but not as a Java Application.

Answer (score 0):

GWT.create() is currently supported in pure java in gwt trunk.  I am using it in a playn project myself {albeit with a slight glitch: [Force GWT compiler to stop pruning invalid CompilationUnits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836760/force-gwt-compiler-to-stop-pruning-invalid-compilationunits) }.

If you download and build trunk, you will be able to circumvent GWT.create() issues by registering ClassInstantiators for whatever class is causing your errors.  In this case, the Window class has a static instance of WindowImpl that is throwing this error when jvm hits the Window class.  If you register a ClassInstantiator for WindowImpl, this will not happen.  Unfortunately, the Window.alert method goes straight to native js, so it may still bomb out on you.

If you don't know how / want to build gwt from trunk, ping me an email and I can send you the jars.  If you still have problems with .alert() being a native method, let me know, and I will create a custom trunk build that defers .alert() into the WindowImpl singleton, so you can have it do something meaningful, like popup an alert message ;-}

If you feel adventurous, download gwt trunk, go into Window, copy the static alert method into an instance-level method on WindowImpl, make the original method delegate to WindowImpl, and then in your java code, call ServerGwtBridge.register(WindowImpl.class, new ClassInstantiator(){...}), and return whatever implementation you want for .alert() in java and android.

Comment: Of course, it would probably be easier to just register a delegate service that is different for each build, and have gwt call Window.alert() while java or android popup a widget.  You would then have to run your calls to alert through the delegate, but it saves you the trouble of hacking against trunk.